# How to calculate the size bucket of an Android device manually (not programmatically)

Tags: android, android-layout

I have tons of Android device specs (Model, Manufacturer, Resolution, Height, Width, Size) in a spreadsheet. How can I perform a theoretical calculation of the size bucket in which each device should ideally fall?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by "size bucket", you mean `-small`, `-normal`, `-large`, `-xlarge`, the answer is "you probably should no longer care". Anything that is running Android 1.x/2.x can be assumed to be `-small` or `-normal`; anything running Android 4.0+ are better handled through more flexible resource qualifiers (e.g., `-sw600dp`).

That being said, the classic rough dividing lines have been:

- `-small` is under 3" diagonal
- `-normal` is 3-5"
- `-large` is 5-10"
- `-xlarge` is over 10"

Comment: Thanks, but that does not explain this anomaly - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19876575/galaxy-mega-vs-other-phablets-and-android-manifest

Comment: @RaviGupta: "that does not explain this anomaly" -- so? Your question here specifically indicates that you want to take guesses for screen size buckets, rather than using what the manufacturer decided to choose for their device. Your guesses will be wrong sometimes, because device manufacturers have the freedom to tinker with these values, as they see fit, if they think that they will get better results.