# Galaxy Mega vs. other Phablets and Android Manifest

Tags: android, android-layout

The manifest entries for my application are as follows -

```
<supports-screens>
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:largeScreens="false"
        android:xlargeScreens="false"
</supports-screens>        

<compatible-screens>

    <!-- small size screens -->
    <screen
            android:screenDensity="ldpi"
            android:screenSize="small" />
    <screen
            android:screenDensity="mdpi"
            android:screenSize="small" />
    <screen
            android:screenDensity="hdpi"
            android:screenSize="small" />
    <screen
            android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
            android:screenSize="small" />
    <screen
            android:screenDensity="480"
            android:screenSize="small" />

    <!-- all normal size screens -->
    <screen
            android:screenDensity="ldpi"
            android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
            android:screenDensity="mdpi"
            android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
            android:screenDensity="hdpi"
            android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
            android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
            android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
            android:screenDensity="480"
            android:screenSize="normal" />

</compatible-screens>
```

When I uploaded the app to Google Play store, the first two devices from the list below (Galaxy Mega) were automatically filtered out. The similar devices below them were not.

Samsung Galaxy Mega 6.3
Size - 6.3 Resolution - 720x1280 DPI - 233

Samsung Galaxy Mega 5.8
Size - 5.8 Resolution - 540x960 DPI - 190

HTC One Max
Size - 5.9 Resolution - 1080x1920 DPI - 373

Samsung Galaxy Note 3
Size - 5.7 Resolution - 1080x1920 DPI - 386

Samsung Galaxy Round
Size - 5.7 Resolution - 1080x1920 DPI - 386

Samsung Galaxy Note II
Size - 5.5 Resolution - 720x1280 DPI - 267

Does anyone have an insight into why Developer Console would treat the two Galaxy Mega devices differently?

Comment: I would recommend getting rid of `<compatible-screens>` entirely. Quoting [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/compatible-screens-element.html): "Caution: Normally, you should not use this manifest element. Using this element can dramatically reduce the potential user base for your application, by not allowing users to install your application if they have a device with a screen configuration that you have not listed."

Comment: @CommonsWare I know they reccomend agaisnt it, but sometimes it is inevitable. for example I absolutely need 2 different apps for phones and for tablets, so I provide google play with 2 apks. one of them needs to filter out all phones, the other filter out all tablets. this is easier said than done because as noted by the first answer, the Galaxy Mega has android:screenSize="large". I am also hoping someone will provide a solution to this.

Comment: otherwise my solution will be to filter it out programatically. in my main activity I will make a check on displayMetrics and start either the phone activity or the tablet activity.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that Samsung Galaxy Mega 6.3 belogs to a android:screenSize="large" category, therefore it gets filtered out by your config.

Try adding

```
<screen
            android:screenDensity="hdpi"
            android:screenSize="large" />
```

if it does not work try also setting density to mdpi or tvdpi(213)

Comment: Thanks, but doing that will make the app available to tons of other tablet devices as well, which is not the desired outcome.